# Android: Floating Action Button Image Resource and Image Drawable Issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-glide, floating-action-button

Library: `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`

XML:

```
  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_16_dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:fabCustomSize="80dp"
            app:maxImageSize="80dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_above="@id/layout_privacycardview"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_football" />
```

Output:
[image: Desired result]

Now, I want to set the image resource programmatically as well as dynamically using Glide.

```
   String url = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSyKmXIim9sp4B4Mn1N_NJtRkzvkStZo_s5pA&usqp=CAU";
        Glide.with(HomeScreenActivity.this).load(url).into(fab);
```

Output:

[image: Issue]

How to set the image resource dynamically using Glide, such that it can have its proper imageSize etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make icon circle as below -

```
 String url = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images? 
 q=tbn:ANd9GcSyKmXIim9sp4B4Mn1N_NJtRkzvkStZo_s5pA&usqp=CAU";

    Glide.with(HomeScreenActivity.this) 
    .load(url)
    .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
    .into(fab);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

.override(width,height)  and pass in desired width and height values and also add .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())

Example :-

```
Glide.with(HomeScreenActivity.this).load(url).override(80,80).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())into(fab);
```